# Can Dialogflow be added as a voice interface to a web app and voice enable web app functionalities?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a question regarding Dialogflow integration into web apps.
I see Dialogflow can be integrated into web as a chatbot(web demo). But the chatbot is text-based and does not naturally speak to you. In addition, web integration uses REST API to send user query back to Dialogflow agent and receive responses from it. Is it possible for users to fully interact with the web app using purely voice? ex: say "open product page", then the voice assistant will reply and navigate the user to the product page.

I haven't found anyone doing this with Dialogflow yet so I'm not sure if Dialoglow is capable of enabling functionalities in a web app. Anyone has ideas on this? thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your query, but as someone whose product uses DF's STT I would suggest you don't rely on it to provide the same experience as the web version.  As a backup, or "optional feature" it may be fine, but I suspect you will struggle with the quality of the interactions.  Wishing you luck, tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [`sessions.detectIntent`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) API, you can see it is able to accept audio as an input and is able to output audio in the response.

```
inputAudio  
string (bytes format)

The natural language speech audio to be processed. This field should be populated iff queryInput is set to an input audio config. A single request can contain up to 1 minute of speech audio data.

A base64-encoded string.
```

In this request, you can specify the [input audio encoding](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryInput#inputaudioconfig) including the sample rate and format.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for your reply. Is it correct that I will need to add a microphone to my webpage myself, receive audio input and send that audio input to DIalogflow for processing? Dialogflow doesn't automatically record audio input from user for us, right? Thanks!

Comment: Correct, you'll have to implement the audio recording based in your client.